# Tracking black objects live streaming

Tags: python-2.7, opencv3.0

I'm trying to make a project that tracks the black objects on the ground with a harsh desert sunny environment and I tried to make some trials but it doesn't work. I tried converting the black pixels in the image to Red because the Red pixels is easy to track (higher intensity) but it doesn't result in what I want. I tried inverting the image (converting the black to white and white to black) but it doesn't give the desired result either. So any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    warp = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ORANGE_MIN = np.array([40, 40, 60], np.uint8)
    ORANGE_MAX = np.array([50, 70, 80], np.uint8)
    hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    Conv_hsv_Gray = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    imf = np.float32(Conv_hsv_Gray) / 255.0  # float conversion/scale
    Desc = cv2.dct(imf)
    sub_to = Desc[0, 0]
    print sub_to
    result_frame = Desc - sub_to
    Fitr = cv2.blur(result_frame, (1, 1))
    Filter2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(Desc, (1, 1), 0)
    iddt1 = cv2.idct(Fitr)
    iddt2 = cv2.idct(Filter2)
    framethreshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, ORANGE_MIN, ORANGE_MAX)
    ret, mask = cv2.threshold(Conv_hsv_Gray, 100, 150, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(warp)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(iddt1, iddt1, mask=mask)
    cv2.imwrite('output2.jpg', framethreshed)
    cv2.imshow("imgOriginal(1)", frame)  # show windows
    cv2.imshow("Masking res(3)", res)  # show windows
    cv2.imshow("mask_inv)", mask_inv)  # show windows
    if cv2.waitKey(60) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break
cap.release()
```